Tag subsequent rows after value in one columnA series changes based on a condition in columnB
I have a problem with the following data:



month
product
version
price
category




1
A
alpha
500
foo


2
A
alpha
500
foo


3
A
alpha
550
foo


4
A
alpha
600
bar


5
A
alpha
500
bar


6
A
alpha
500
faz


7
A
alpha
500
faz


8
A
alpha
500
faz


9
A
alpha
500
faz


10
A
alpha
500
foo


4
A
beta
700
bar


5
A
beta
800
bar


6
A
beta
800
faz


7
A
beta
800
faz


8
A
beta
800
faz


9
A
beta
700
faz


10
A
beta
500
foo


1
B
alpha
200
foo


2
B
alpha
200
foo


3
B
alpha
250
foo


4
B
alpha
250
bar


5
B
alpha
250
bar


6
B
alpha
250
faz


7
B
alpha
250
faz


8
B
alpha
250
faz


9
B
alpha
500
faz


10
B
alpha
500
foo


4
B
beta
700
bar


5
B
beta
800
bar


6
B
beta
800
faz


7
B
beta
800
faz


8
B
beta
800
faz


9
B
beta
700
faz


10
B
beta
500
foo



What I would like to do is group by the product and version, and tag the rows where the price remains the same BUT the category changes from the preceding month for each product+version group. Additionally I want to tag all rows below the first category change where the price is consistent with the last row of the preceding category
I  have tried approaches in SQL with LEAD and LAG as well as CASE WHEN exists but I am not able to get the logic to work as desired. My approaches have been able to tag one following month but not several months after a category change.
I am also open to implementing a solution in python.
The tag column below represents the desired output.



month
product
version
price
category
tag




1
A
alpha
500
foo
OK


2
A
alpha
500
foo
OK


3
A
alpha
550
foo
OK


4
A
alpha
600
bar
OK


5
A
alpha
500
bar
OK


6
A
alpha
500
faz
FLAG


7
A
alpha
500
faz
FLAG


8
A
alpha
500
faz
FLAG


9
A
alpha
500
faz
FLAG


10
A
alpha
500
foo
FLAG


4
A
beta
700
bar
OK


5
A
beta
800
bar
OK


6
A
beta
800
faz
FLAG


7
A
beta
800
faz
FLAG


8
A
beta
800
faz
FLAG


9
A
beta
700
faz
OK


10
A
beta
500
foo
OK


1
B
alpha
200
foo
OK


2
B
alpha
200
foo
OK


3
B
alpha
250
foo
OK


4
B
alpha
250
bar
FLAG


5
B
alpha
250
bar
FLAG


6
B
alpha
250
faz
FLAG


7
B
alpha
250
faz
FLAG


8
B
alpha
250
faz
FLAG


9
B
alpha
500
faz
OK


10
B
alpha
500
foo
OK


4
B
beta
700
bar
OK


5
B
beta
800
bar
OK


6
B
beta
800
faz
FLAG


7
B
beta
800
faz
FLAG


8
B
beta
800
faz
FLAG


9
B
beta
700
faz
OK


10
B
beta
500
foo
OK



I have tried this approach:
WITH cte AS ( SELECT , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, version ORDER BY month ASC) AS rn FROM table ), 
flux AS ( SELECT c., CASE WHEN EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM cte c2 WHERE (c.product = c2.product AND c.version = c2.version) AND c2.rn < c.rn AND c2.price BETWEEN -1000 AND 1000 AND c.category != c2.category ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS tag FROM cte c ORDER BY month ) 
SELECT * FROM flux


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

A SQL solution requires a recursive query, because of the necessary iteration. A python solution wil hence be much more straight-forward; just read the data sorted by product version and month and then loop through the rows to decide whether to flag a row or not depending on the previous row. I wonder what kept you from achieving this.

What DBMS are you using? Always tag your SQL requests with your DBMS, so we know what SQL features are available. But as mentioned, this is more a task for a programming language, so you'll be better of with python. And the required select * from mytable order by product, version, month probably works in every RDBMS.

There may be more sophisticated approaches, but I would probbably first number my rows per product and version and flag the changing rows and then iterate though the rows to flag the consecutive rows. For the first part we need window functions. And as to the next part: "iterate" translates to "recursive query" in SQL.
WITH 
  numbered_and_flagged AS
  (
    SELECT
      t.*,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY product, version ORDER BY month) AS rn,
      CASE WHEN price = LAG(price) OVER (PARTITION BY product, version ORDER BY month)
            AND category <> LAG(category) OVER (PARTITION BY product, version ORDER BY month)
        THEN 'FLAG'
        ELSE 'OK'
      END AS tag
    FROM mytable t
  ),
  cte (month, product, version, price, category, rn, tag) AS 
  ( 
    SELECT month, product, version, price, category, rn, tag FROM numbered_and_flagged WHERE rn = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
      n.month, n.product, n.version, n.price, n.category, n.rn,
      CASE WHEN cte.tag = 'FLAG' AND cte.price = n.price THEN 'FLAG' ELSE n.tag END AS tag
    FROM cte
    JOIN numbered_and_flagged n ON n.product = cte.product
                               AND n.version = cte.version
                               AND n.rn      = cte.rn + 1
  ) 
SELECT month, product, version, price, category, tag
FROM cte
ORDER BY product, version, month;

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/XSdSVrTd
You haven't tagged the request with the DBMS you are using, so you may have to adjust above query slightly. In PostgreSQL for instance you must add the keyword RECURSIVE. Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/tf1CWCyh
